# How do I sort elements of 2 lists by their id which have been merged?

Tags: java

I have merged the above list but need to sort it based on the id param. How do I do that in the easiest and the optimal way possible? 
I have a set of 2 users which I initially merged and now I would like to sort them based on their id and then display the results. Any ideas?

```
  import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;


/*
 * To execute Java, please define "static void main" on a class
 * named Solution.
 *
 * If you need more classes, simply define them inline.
 */

class Employee {
  public String name;
  public int id;

  Employee(String name, int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  }


  public String toString() {
    return "<name: " + this.name + ", id: " + this.id + ">";
  }
}

class Person {
  public String name;
  public int id;

  Person(String name, int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "<name: " + this.name + ", id: " + this.id + ">";
  }
}


public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employee = generateEmployees();
    List<Person> persons = generatePersons();


ArrayList<Object> merged = new ArrayList<Object>(employee);
        merged.addAll(person);
        System.out.println("merged:"+merged +"\n");


   for(int i=0;i<users.size();i++){
        if(person.get(i).id<=5){
        System.out.println("UserName:"+person.get(i).name+"\n");
        }
      }
     for(int i=0;i<employee.size();i++){
       if(employee.get(i).id<=5){
        System.out.println("DesignerName:"+employee.get(i).name+"\n");
        }
      }

});

  }
```

Thanks in advance!
I have looked at several methods online for sorting but couldnt figureo ut which was the best way to use it.Just want to display results once its sorted

Comment: Not sure I am missing something, but probably the easiest way would be to make the `User` class implement the `Comparable` interface and then just call `merged.Sort()`. You can also take a look at Streams.

Comment: can you explain with an example?

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://www.journaldev.com/780/comparable-and-comparator-in-java-example) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` and `Designer` must extend from one same class. (or `Designer extand user`).
Then you create a Comparator ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) and you use `merged.sort (myComparator)` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-))

[**EDIT**]

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<User> {
    @Override
    public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.id, o2.id);
    }
}


public class User {
    public String name;
    public int id;

    User(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "<name: " + this.name + ", id: " + this.id + ">";
    }

}



public class Designer extends User{
    Designer(String enter code herename, int id) {
        super(name, id);
    }
}


public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...

        ArrayList<User> merged = new ArrayList<User>(designers);
        merged.addAll(users);
        merged.sort(new MyComparator());
...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have list of `User` that is called `users`:

```
users.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getId)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: merged has the new set of users. but its an arraylist<object> , will this way still work?

Comment: also whats getid()? do i need to create a new class called Mergedusers?

Comment: You should not merge `User` and `Designer` to `ArrayList<Object>`. Beside that they both have same fields, try something like this:

`public class Designer extends User{
 
 public Designer(String name, int id) {
  super(name, id);
 }

}`

Then use `ArrayList<User>` and sorting method.

Comment: should i define getID() in user or designer?

Comment: You should define it in User